# Should I use Perl/Tk, Tcl::Tk or Tkx for a Perl GUI?

Tags: perl, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit, tkx

I really like `Perl/Tk`, but have come to the opinion that it's DOA. I think `Tcl::Tk` and `Tkx` are better solutions. Assume I drop `Perl/Tk`. Is the "most supported" route to go with `Tcl::Tk` (which hasn't been updated since 2007, and whose author seemingly cannot be reached), or `Tkx`? Are either of these actively used/supported?

Comment: If you want adopt Tcl::Tk you could try this: http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_adopt_module

Answer (score 16):

Under the hood both [Tcl::Tk](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tcl::Tk) and [Tkx](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tkx) use the [Tcl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tcl) module as a bridge to Tcl/Tk. The difference is in the API they present to Perl.

Tkx was developed by ActiveState, who use it in the GUI for their tools. (e.g. PPM) It's actively used, though it's hard to say how widely. It's supported as well, but because it's such a thin layer over Tcl there's not a great deal to support. In a way that's a good thing -- there's little to change or break -- but it does give the impression of abandonware.

Tcl::Tk started as a side project to demonstrate that API compatibility with Perl/Tk was possible. I love the idea of this -- it would be wonderful to only need to change `use Tk` to `use Tcl::Tk` and get the benefits of newer versions of Tcl/Tk like tile (theme) support. Unfortunately, it's not there yet. There seems to be some work being done, but not a lot. It could really use more developers.

Personally, I use Tkx. If you're experienced at developing in Perl/Tk the transition isn't too painful, but I think it would be a difficult place to start. The worst part is that you need to refer to the [Tcl/Tk documentation](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/docs/ActiveTcl/8.5/tcl/tk_contents.htm) in order to use it. That's great if you know Tcl as there are very few surprises introduced by the bridge to Perl, but if you don't it's awkward to translate from an unfamiliar language.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't mind helping on it (Tcl::Tk) , but I wrote the author at every email I could find, and it bounced back. His wiki is gone, his we site is gone, it's depressing. And google doesn't help much.

Comment: If you want adopt Tcl::Tk you could try this: http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_adopt_module

Comment: @xcramps: You can join the mailing list by sending a message to tcltk-subscribe@perl.org. I've seen Vadim on there occasionally.

Comment: I recently adopted Tkx. Hopefully that helps it not seem too abandoned.

Answer (score 8):

I have had good result with [wxPerl](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/index.html), [here is a short article on O'Reilly](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2001/09/12/wxtutorial1.html)

**Note:** I was targeting win32 and this was about 5 years ago.

Comment: I don't think that's at all helpful for answering the question that was asked. It doesn't even help answer the tangential question of what toolkit should be used since your answer is based on five year old information on a technology that is rapidly evolving.

Comment: @Bryan: wxPerl is much more relevant now that 5 years ago thanks to the effort made by Gabor, Adam and others to build Padre, a big wxPerl application.

Comment: @dolmen: that may be true, but the question was specifically about Tk which is why I said I didn't think the answer was helpful. I'm all for posting other options when someone says "which tool is better" or "are there any alternatives" but that wasn't the question. <shrug> I'm glad to hear that wxPerl exists and is relevant.